# Que veut dire « avérer »?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J’ai lu quelques unes ressources en ligne qui expliquent le mot « avérer ». Cependant, elles n’apportent pas assez de clarté pour moi.

Selon le Wiktionnaire, ce mot veut dire « reconnaitre ou faire reconnaitre pour vrai. »

Ça laisse penser que le mot peut remplacer « démontrer ». Peut-on dire, par exemple :
« Je vais avérer que la porte de nôtre maison est serrée » pour exprimer que je reviens à la porte pour voir la serrure et garantir qu’elle est ouverte, en essayant de l’ouvrir ?

Je voudrais aussi savoir si la tournure « j’avère que » peut tenir lieu de « il me semble que »,  pourvu qu’un événement imprévu fait disparaître le moindre doute d’une pensée. Un exemple : « J’avère que ce chemin est peu praticable pour les voitures, parce qu’il est trop étroit, regorge des virages ingérables et il est mal revêtu. » Et si cet emploi ne vous étonne pas, faut-il que l’interlocuteur peut aussi comprendre que ce chemin soit impraticable si je veux l’utiliser ?

Ce mot peut aussi être utilisé comme un verbe réfléchi. À vrai dire, j’ai seulement vu le mot dans l’apparence de « s’avère ». C’est pourquoi ça me surprend un peu que le Wiktionnaire n’a pas de renseignements dédiés à cette conjugaison. Le Trésor donne lieu à disséquer le mot pour tout le monde qui est né en France, mais moi, je de mal à comprendre ces phrases dures qui sont tirées des livres que je ne connais pas de tout. Tous ce que je saisis, ce que l’emploi de « s’avérer » est un peu comme « sembler d’être comme … », hormis que je crois que « s’avérer » exprime plus de certitude.

Pouvez vous me donner des renseignements que je peux comprendre facilement ?

Comment: Il y aurait beaucoup à dire pour répondre mais je viens de trouver cette page sur le site de l'Université de Montréal [*Avérer, avéré et s’avérer*](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/observations/averer.htm) qui reprend bien tout ce que j'ai trouvé par ailleurs, et je ne pourrais que faire du copier coller pour répondre. Bonne lecture !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est une de ces expressions qui s'emploient presque toujours à la troisième personne du singulier, dans sa forme réfléchie : "il s'avère que…".  Cela veut dire un nombre de choses différentes avec quelques différences assez subtiles :

- Tout d'abord, "il est établi que…", "il est démontré que…"
- Mais aussi synonyme de l'expression anglaise "it is proving (par exemple) difficult to understand X"… Avec ce dernier usage "il s'avère" exprime une notion d'"impression tentative".
- Mais on peut aussi traduire en anglais par "it transpires that…" donc "après de nombreux obscurcissements, frustrations et impasses éventuels, la vérité qui ressort est que…"

Peut-on l'utiliser d'une façon plus aventureuse ? "Nous avérons…" Il faudrait sans doute entendre les explications des francophones de ce forum, mais pour moi, en tant qu'anglo-saxon, je pense que cette utilisation non réfléchie est réservée exclusivement pour un registre très formel : journaux "sérieux" (Le Monde !), textes juridiques, …

Comment: Une chose peut avérer un fait. Ce n'est pas du langage courant mais ça existe.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Et pour corroborer ce que tu dis je cite la page référencée dans mon commentaire ci-dessus : *L’expression avérer un fait, c’est-à-dire « le rendre certain » (NPR), est le seul usage que la langue moderne a retenu. Encore faut-il souligner que cet usage se limite à la langue didactique.*

Answer (score 1):

Le petit Robert (d'un usage beaucoup plus pratique que les références données dans la question) indique que *avérer* est vieilli ou didactique, c'est-à-dire que l'on peut le connaître, mais qu'il n'est pas à utiliser dans une conversation courante ; peu de gens savent que l'on peut :

> Avérer un fait : donner ce fait comme certain.

En revanche sa forme pronominale, a pour synonyme : *apparaître, se montrer, paraître, se révéler*.

On peut comprendre son utilisation en le remplaçant par *confirmer* et son contraire *infirmer* :

> Ce raisonnement s'est avéré juste : ce raisonnement est *confirmé*.
>
> Ce raisonnement s'est avéré faux : ce raisonnement est *infirmé*.

Comment: *Avéré juste* contient un pléonasme. *Avéré faux* un oxymore. Le truc est que *avéré* contient déjà *vrai* et certains vous tapperaient sur les doigts pour avoir oublié son étymologie.

Comment: +1 "s'avérer juste" et "s'avérer faux" ne devraient plus être considérés comme des pléonasmes/oxymores dans la forme pronominale d'avérer. http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr84vWAiHFbX6w&page=93whD2ubjGzM.html

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tant mieux. Qu'on oublie l'étymologie, sinon il faudrait insister comme certains anglos qui prétendent que *decimate* (et donc *décimer*) ne s'emploie que si on élimine un sur dix. Et il faudrait écrire *compter* et *conter* pareil car étymologique c'est exactement le même mot! Etc. etc.

Comment: @jlliagre Nous sommes ici dans une phase d'évolution de l'acception d'un mot : de rigoureux et enraciné dans l'étymologie, l'usage amène une souplesse (certains diront un détournement, un affadissement, une dégradation, un affaiblissement...) acceptée par beaucoup.

Comment: @cl-r « C'est vrai que c'est vrai » ;-)